# Does Right to Represent mean if the person clears interview , he is bound to the staffing company?

Tags: interviewing

Does "Right to Represent" mean if the person clears interview, he is bound to the staffing company? Or is it only for representation to the interview and not related to whether or not the person is offered the job in future?

Comment: Which country?  And did you sign anything?

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking of using a recruiter to land you an interview and then skipping out on them. Is that the case? Doe sit sound like a decent thing to do?

Comment: @Mawg It could also be about someone who is worried that a recruiter's terms may be overly restrictive in what they can do ... I don't think there's enough detail to decide.

Comment: It could well be. And, yes, the OP hasn't said (+1). Maybe he should read [ask]. If that is the case, I would give up both the recruiter and the job, and look elsewhere

Comment: @Mawg I don't understand what it is about this question that makes you think the OP has malicious intent. It sounds like they want to know which entity they'll actually work for if they get the job, which seems reasonable, though a) they should make that clearer and b) seems like they should ask the staffing company.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "bound to" the staffing company? Are you just wondering who'll sign your paychecks or something else?

Comment: I don't really see "which entity they'll actually work for if they get the job" in the question, but it might well be simply that they have never applied for a job though a recruiter before. I think we need clarification from the OP.

Comment: As a general rule, you should never sign something you don't understand or agree to as you are legally bound to those terms regardless if they are enforceable or not.

Answer (score 7):

> Does "Right to Represent" mean if the person clears interview, he is
>   bound to the staffing company? Or is it only for representation to the
>   interview and not related to whether or not the person is offered the
>   job in future?

The "Right to Represent" gives the recruiter the exclusive right to represent you to this company for this job and for the duration agreed to in the document.

The representation goes through the interview to the job offer and acceptance.

You should not attempt to skip out on your commitment given by signing this document. Doing so would certainly ruin your relationship with the recruiter and recruiting company, but could also ruin your relationship with the potential employer. Going back on your word is seldom a good career move.

If you have any hesitation about signing a Right to Represent document, you should not sign it and should move on to another job opportunity/recruiter.